# Local Gravitational Time Dilation Effects on Entangled Particles

Tags: gravity, time, quantum-entanglement

If Alice is located just beyond the event horizon of a black hole, and Bob is at some other point in space with de minimis gravitiational effect, what, if any, effect would it have on the "spooky action at a distance" between these two entangled entities?

I'm a wannabe sci-fi writer looking to exploit untested but possibly plausible concepts derived from my own madness and admittedly poor understanding of the universe.

Comment: *within the sphere of gravitational influence of a black hole* What does that mean? Gravity has infinite range; it just gets weaker the farther you go. Do you mean she is inside the event horizon of the black hole (and thus doomed)?

Comment: Ok, that's fair.  Let's say Alice's containment is onboard a star faring vessel hanging out in the spot that experiences the greatest gravitational effect without crossing the event horizon.  Or, perhaps she is hurtling towards the event horizon and we take a reading immediately before she crosses the point of no return (assuming the observers are omnipotent and can compare both readings at the same time).